# Question on the representative of the longest Weyl element of $\mathrm{SO}(2n+1)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, weyl-group

Let $w_{m}$ be the $m \times m$ matrix with ones on the non-principal diagonal and zeros elsewhere.
Let $V$ be the $2n+2$-dimensional quadratic space with the symmetric bilinear form $\left<,\right>$ given by $w_{2n+2}$.

Let $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_{n+1},e_{-n-1},\cdots,e_{-2},e_{-1}\}$ be the corresponding standard basis of $V$ such that $\left<e_{i},e_{-j} \right>=\delta_{ij}$ and $\left<e_{i},e_{j} \right>=0$.

Let $G$ be the special orthogonal group of $W_{2n+2}$, that is,  $G=\mathrm{SO}(W_{2n+2})$ and let $G'$ be the  subgroup of $G$ fixing $e_{n+1}-e_{-n-1}$. Let $B'$ be the Borel subgroup of $G'$.

I call the element $w_0' \in G'$ represents the longest element of $G'$ if $B'w_0'B'$ is the big cell of $G'$.

I am wondering whether $\begin{pmatrix} & & w_n \\ & I_2& \\ w_n& &  \end{pmatrix}$ or $w_{2n+2}$ would be representative of the longest Weyl element of $G'$.

Furthermore, let $P'=M'U'$ be the maximal parabolic subgroup of $G'$ such that $M'=\begin{pmatrix} m& &  \\ & I_2& \\ & &m^*  \end{pmatrix}$ where $m \in \mathrm{GL}_n$.

Then I am wondering what element in $G'$ represents the longest $M'$-reduced Weyl element of $G'$.

Is it $\begin{pmatrix} & & I_n \\ & I_2& \\ I_n& &  \end{pmatrix}$?

Thank you in advance!